# Excel - MyFitnessPal - Combine row data from Break/Lunch/Dinner/Snacks

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I'd like to combine the nutrition data from multiple meals during a single day onto a single row.

Current Sheet:
[image]

Desired Result:
[image]

My knowledge of Excel is limited, and non-existent in terms of VBA.

Answer (score 1):

- Create a new sheet. 
  Copy the column headers.
- Put a de-duped list of the dates in Column `A` of the new sheet. 
  (Methods for doing that are documented all over the place.)
- Enter `=SUMIF(Input!$A:$A, $A2, Input!C:C)`
  (where `Input` is the name of the existing sheet, with all the meal data)
  into Cell `C2` of the new sheet.
- Select and drag/fill down to cover all the dates
  and right to cover all the nutrients, etc.
- If desired, copy and paste values.

Here’s a screenshot
showing the data from Columns `A`, `C` and `D` of your file:

[image: spreadsheet]